# Error using Json-feed for login: ACS50011

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, claims-based-identity, federated-identity, wif

I have an RP for which I've built a login page using the Json feed from ACS.  The IP images are linked to the `.LoginUrl` attribute of the feed and when I click on one of the images it correctly jumps to that IP's page.

Entering my credentials, however, I'm redirected to a page on the appfabriclabs.com site with the following error:

```
HTTP Error Code: 400 
Message: ACS50000: There was an error issuing a token. 
ACS50011: The RP ReplyTo address is missing. Either the RP ReplyToAddresses
are not configured or an invalid wreply 'https://www.skillscore.it/' was received
in the sign-in request.
```

the RP is configured in the App Labs site with a **returnUrl** of:

```
https://www.skillscore.it/Home/FederationResult
```

and in looking at the **wreply** parameter in the feed, I see:

```
https%3a%2f%2fskillscore.accesscontrol.appfabriclabs.com%3a443%2fv2%2fwsfederation
```

According to some SO articles like [[this one](http://https://skillscore.accesscontrol.appfabriclabs.com:443/v2/wsfederation)] the return url of the app should be a prefix of the wreply parameter - which is clearly not the case here.

so... what have I done wrong now?

- e

p.s. one interesting bit of info: in the Application Integration page of ACS there is a link to the ACS-hosted login page.  the link used there seems to differ from the one I'm given in the feed; in particular, the ACS-hosted page uses a **wctx** of:

```
pr%3dwsfederation%26rm%3dhttps%253a%252f%252fwww.skillscore.it%252f
```

whereas the feed gives me:

```
pr%3dwsfederation%26rm%3dhttps%253a%252f%252fwww.skillscore.it%252f%26ry%3dhttps%253a%252f%252fwww.skillscore.it%252f
```

so I don't know what that's worth but maybe it's a clue to what's wrong.

*** update ***

decoded, that last string is:

```
pr=wsfederation
&rm=https%3a%2f%2fwww.skillscore.it%2f
&ry=https%3a%2f%2fwww.skillscore.it%2f
```

which clearly shows the Json feed is providing an **ry** that is not present in the ACS-hosted page... meaning anything to anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok. my bad.  apparently, when I was fetching the Json feed, the URL I used did not have the **reply_to** set correctly.